# Trying to list 8 entries only with ls

Tags: unix, ls

I'm new to Unix and trying to teach myself navigation.

I'm trying to make an alias in my .bashrc file, that will list the first 8 entries of my home folder.

```
alias start= "ls -1 ~"
```

is what I've figured out so far, How would I limit it to only 8 though? I can't find any arguments in the ls command that would do this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `head` to get the first 8.

```
alias start='ls -1 ~ | head -8'
```

Answer (score 1):

Pipe it to `head`?

```
alias start="\ls -1 ~ | head -n 8"
```

**EDIT**. After some testing, if you have an alias named `ls` (and most standard installation put one by default), you want to prepend backslash `\` to `ls` in your `start` alias declaration.
Backslash disables aliasing and executes the standard shell command.

Comment: Thanks, looks like I need more practice!